# Adobe After Effects labels: Project vs Layer/Timeline

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe

**How do I label my Composition clips in the Layer/Timeline panel, based on how they are categorized/binned in the Project panel?**

- I have a composition created by Adobe Premiere of about 100 items
- I've set the label for each clip/asset in the Project pane

  - I have bins for each label
  - I did this because the different clips were shot with different light, and I want to correct for this
- I see my clips in the Layer/Timeline panel
- ...with labels...
- yet the labels are NOT the same as how they appear for the same assets above, in the Project panel!

**Q: why are these labels inconsistent?**

**Q: I want to apply a effect preset I have to a subset of the clips, which is already labelled and binned in the Project pane.  How?**

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking on the "Layer Name"/"Source Name" column title in the timeline.  It should toggle between the name in your Project bin, and the name you've given the layer in the comp.

[image: source name]
[image: layer name]